# RestSharp RequestFormat not working

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I have the following code:

```
1.  var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:52347/");
2.  var xmlRequest = new RestRequest("api/students/{id}", Method.GET);
3.  //xmlRequest.AddHeader(HttpRequestHeader.Accept.ToString(), "text/xml");
4.  xmlRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;
5.  xmlRequest.AddUrlSegment("id", "5");
6.  
7.  IRestResponse xmlResponse = client.Execute(xmlRequest);
8.  var xmlContent = xmlResponse.Content;
9.  
10. Console.WriteLine(xmlContent);
```

However, with this setup, I'm still getting a return format of JSON.  If I uncomment line 3 and comment out line 4 it works, but I'd prefer not to do that.  It seems like line 4 doesn't do anything at all. Is there something I'm missing or do I have to use that 3rd line to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RestRequest.RequestFormat property tells RestSharp what type of data you are sending to the server; it does not tell it what data to return. Instead, that is managed by the request.

In this example, line 4 isn't doing anything because you are not sending any data to the server.

Line 3, however, is telling the server what type of data to return. So I'd leave that in. Or, if this isn't how it should be working, look at the code responding to the API request and how the API is determining the format of the data to return.